# Difference in use case between application load balancer and API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

I’m trying to pick up API gateway.

What are the different use cases for alb vs API gateway? I’ll be honest to say that I am not completely familiar with the concept of an API. I know we can invoke it backend, and the analogy that it’s a restaurant menu. However, beyond that, I am not clear what the difference is. Is it that applications using ALB has a user interface, but not API gateway? I tried reading through documentation on the features, but got even more lost. As such, I am hoping someone can share the use cases for both services so that I can visualise what it’s used for and the reason for the features. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use Application Load Balancer over API Gateway in AWS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63373473/when-to-use-application-load-balancer-over-api-gateway-in-aws)

Answer (score 2):

API GW is focused on API and has some additional options - e.g. API definition via swagger, execution of a lambda function, converting the call to an event bridge event, support of authenticators (iam, cognito), multiple deployment stages etc.

The load balancer listens on a port and that's about it.

Q: In what cases would you require these API GW features as opposed to just using an ALB?

A: One obvious benefit is a serverless or "low code". Let's say you want an API which processes asynchronous requests.

It is possible to create an API endpoint which queues all incoming requests to a SQS queue with just one AWS CLI command with no programming (provided the resources do exist):
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-aws-services.html

Each API endpoint can be served by a different AWS resource including EC2/ALB.

ALB is well suited for things like traditional monolithic applications (LAMP, Java application servers etc.)

Comment: I see, in what cases would you require these features as opposed to just using an alb? Thanks for your time, I understand this question is rly basic.