# What is the maximum limit on aws lambda inputstream size?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, inputstream, user-input

Following is the signature for aws lambda method which takes one inputStream param. In my usecase this inputstream param could have size of GBs also. Is there any maximum limit on lambda for this inputstream ?

```
public void handler(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) 
throws IOException {

}
```

If yes what all option I could use for taking inputstream in lambda? In my usecase I want to avoid taking text-stream in s3 file.
This inputstream consist of huge number of csv formatted data records. Client is triggering this lambda by aws-sdk api and want to pass this csv records as lambda inputstream.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Request payload limit with AWS API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358922/request-payload-limit-with-aws-api-gateway)

Comment: Using S3 as the alternative input source is the only workaround I know of

Comment: @mattfreake Thanks for replying. I already saw this limits. Just wanted to know if any workaround exists for extending this limit. Now it seems I have to look for S3 option only.